# I want to wrap the firebase image path in v-for

Tags: firebase, vue.js, nuxt.js

*I'm not a developer, so the question might look stupid. I ask for your understanding.*

There is an existing code with v-for

```
v-tab-item(
  v-for="(item, index) in getCharacterSkinList"
  :key="index"
)
  v-img(:src="require('~/static/img/skin/' + item.id + '_' + getSkinId + getSkinState + '.webp')"
```

Current Changes

```
v-tab-item(
  v-for="(item, index) in getCharacterSkinList"
  :key="index"
)
  img(:src="imageSrc")


export default {
    mounted() {
        const skinId = this.$store.getters['skin/getSkinId']
        const state = this.$store.getters['skin/getSkinState']
        const storageRef = this.$fire.storage.ref()

        this.getCharacterSkinList.forEach((item, index) => {
            const imageRef = storageRef.child(
                `skin/${item.id}_${skinId}${state}.webp`
            )
            imageRef
                .getDownloadURL()
                .then((url) => {
                    this.$set(this.imageSrc, index, url)
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error, imageSrc)
                })
        })
        this.$store.dispatch('skin/asyncCharacterSkin')
    },
}
```

in this case, getters works successfully.
but failed to load item.id.

I tried

```
v-img(:src="getImageSrc(item.id)")


methods: {
    getImageSrc(id) {
        const skinId = this.$store.getters['skin/getSkinId']
        const state = this.$store.getters['skin/getSkinState']
        const storageRef = this.$fire.storage.ref()
        const imageRef = storageRef.child(`skin/${id}_${skinId}${state}.webp`)
        return imageRef.getDownloadURL()
    },
}
```

I tried to change it to method, but it did not work because returned prosmised.

What other ways can I try?

Answer (score 1):

`getDownloadURL()` is an asynchronous method so you should declare your method as `async` and use `await`, as follows (untested):

```
async getImageSrc(id) {
    const skinId = this.$store.getters['skin/getSkinId']
    const state = this.$store.getters['skin/getSkinState']
    const storageRef = this.$fire.storage.ref()
    const imageRef = storageRef.child(`skin/${id}_${skinId}${state}.webp`)
    const downloadURL = await imageRef.getDownloadURL();
    return downloadURL;
},
```

Comment: I didn't write it down, but I tried. The same error occurs.

`[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "src". Expected String, Object, got Promise `

dose not work img or v-img src